# Grinding noise after initial starting

Tags: noise, saturn

My 2007 Saturn Vue with 161,000 miles on it. It has been a really good car, but lately it has been making a grinding noise after it starts, continues upon acceleration

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does the grinding noise change as you rev the engine, or does it change with the speed you are driving? Can you narrow down where it's coming from, like the engine, or a wheel?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Lots of possibilities but I'd start with things attached to the serpentine belt.  Power steering pump, water pump, alternator, idler pulley, AC compressor.  Any of these could be the issue and all could be worn at 161K miles.

Comment: to Paulster, yes, it continues as I accelerate but gets quieter about 5 miles down the road...sounds like it is coming from the right side of the engine area